# factor(x**2+x+1) is not working in sympy? Is there any solution to find factors?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to find the factors of function x**2+x+1.

Most of the suggetions are to use factor and you get the answer. However, factor(f) doesn't work for all the equations.

I also tried factor(f,gaussian=True) but gives the same result.

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
f = x**2 + x + 1
sp.factor(f)
```

Output of the code: x**2 + x + 1

Expected output: complex roots

-1/2 - sqrt(3)*i/2

-1/2 + sqrt(3)*i/2

Comment: What's the incorrect result you are getting? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Math wise you should know this has no real solution by looking at the discriminate `b**2-4ac` which is -3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use [solveset](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html) :

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
f = x**2 + x + 1
polyRoots = sp.solveset(f, x)
print(polyRoots)
```

and you'll get complex factors